# How does gensim manage to find the most similar words so fast?

Tags: python, time-complexity, gensim, word2vec, similarity

Let's say we train a model with more than 1 million words. In order to find the most similar words we need to calculate the distance between the embedding of the test word and embeddings of all the 1 million words words, and then find the nearest words. It seems that Gensim calculate the results very fast. Although when I want to calculate the most similar, my function is extremely slow:

```
def euclidean_most_similars (model, word, topn = 10):
  distances = {}
  vec1 = model[word]
  for item in model.wv.vocab:
    if item!= node:
      vec2 = model[item]
      dist = np.linalg.norm(vec1 - vec2)
      distances[(node, item)] = dist
  sorted_distances = sorted(distances.items(), key=operator.itemgetter(1))
```

I would like to know how Gensim manages to calculate the most nearest words so fast and what is an efficient way to calculate the most similares.

Comment: One thing right near the top of the [word2vec documentation](https://radimrehurek.com/gensim/models/word2vec.html) is "Make sure you have a C compiler before installing Gensim, to use the optimized word2vec routines (70x speedup compared to plain NumPy implementation, https://rare-technologies.com/parallelizing-word2vec-in-python/)." which gives you a hint to at least some of the optimization. Beyond that, the [source code](https://github.com/RaRe-Technologies/gensim) is freely available

Comment: As for how to improve the efficiency of your own code, that might be a better question for [codereview.se]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @g-anderson commented, the `gensim` source can be reviewed to see exactly what it does. However, `gensim` is not actually using any of its own optimized Cython or compiled-C code as part of its `most_similar()` method – which can be reviewed at:

https://github.com/RaRe-Technologies/gensim/blob/b287fd841c31d0dfa899d784da0bd5b3669e104d/gensim/models/keyedvectors.py#L689

Instead, by using `numpy`/`scipy` bulk array operations, those libraries' highly optimized code will take advantage of both CPU primitives and multithreading to calculate *all* the relevant similarities far faster than an interpreted Python loop.

(The key workhorse is the `numpy` `dot` operation: one call which creates an ordered array of all the similarities – skipping the loop & your interim-results `dict` entirely. But the `argsort`, passing through to `numpy` implementations as well, likely also outperforms the idiomatic `sorted()`.)